# gunicorn status is active (exited) but showing not running in monit

Tags: python, linux, django, gunicorn, init

I am trying to setup a new django project on a server from scratch (django+gunicorn+nginx) and I have everything correct except the init scripts for gunicorn.

if I run the gunicorn command manually it works and I can view my site on the ip address, but when I try to do `service gunicorn start` it gives me this output and it doesn't work...

```
gunicorn-project.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/gunicorn-project; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-11-17 04:23:56 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1656 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/gunicorn-project start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]:   from multiprocessing import cpu_count
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]: /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn-project2.py:3: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '/
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]:   from os import environ
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]: /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn-project3.py:2: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]:   from multiprocessing import cpu_count
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]: /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn-project3.py:3: RuntimeWarning: Parent module '
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]:   from os import environ
Nov 17 04:23:56 project gunicorn-project[1656]:  *
Nov 17 04:23:56 project systemd[1]: Started gunicorn-project.service.
Nov 17 04:25:01 project systemd[1]: Started gunicorn-project.service.
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening... this is the file references in the output...

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
errorlog = '/home/gunicorn-project/log/gunicorn/error.log'
accesslog = '/home/gunicorn-project/log/gunicorn/access.log'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the very same error message thrown at me (were you also following a Digital Ocean tutorial?) and spent quite a few hours trying to figure it out. I don't know if you still need it, but perhaps I can spare someone else from wasting as much time as I did.

I managed to fix it (after several different attempts) by:

1. Stopping gunicorn:

   `sudo systemctl stop gunicorn`
2. Changing writing permissions in both directories containing `gunicorn.service`:

   `sudo chmod u+x /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gunicorn-project.service`

   `sudo chmod u+x /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-project.service`
3. Manually deleting and rebuilding the `gunicorn-project.service` symlink:

   `unlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gunicorn-project.service`

   `rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gunicorn-project.service`

   `ln -s /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-project.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gunicorn-project.service`
4. Reloading gunicorn daemon:

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Restarting gunicorn:

   `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`

   `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn`

And the status changed to `active (running)`. Basically, at some point, I installed gunicorn without setting proper permissions. Once I redid those steps with the right permissions, gunicorn was able to execute as intended.

OBS: my file was named `gunicorn.service`, which I believe is the default. I changed to `gunicorn-project.service` to match OP's terminology.